# default back button in navigation drawer doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I have created an app which uses one activity (Navigation Drawer) and a fragment. But I'm unable to use toolbar back button to navigate back from the fragment to the main activity. Hardware back button works perfectly. I know that I need to override onOptionsItemSelected, catch android.R.id.home, check if there is something in the back stack and then pop it. After changing the fragment, "burger" button changes to "back arrow", but when I click on it the overridden method "onOptionsItemSelected" is never called, rather on click of the back button NavigationDrawer menu opens.

**NOTE: I have referred many answers in the StackOverflow including [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48185871/navigation-drawer-back-button-in-fragments) which is the same as that of my problem but that did not work for me. I have been working on this for a week any help is greatly appreciated. Please do not down vote. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48185871/navigation-drawer-back-button-in-fragments)**

Here is my code

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    public void init() {
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                Log.d("Backstack Count", String.valueOf(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()));
                if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
                    showUpButton(false);
                } else {
                    showUpButton(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void showUpButton(boolean show) {
        // To keep states of ActionBar and ActionBarDrawerToggle synchronized,
        // when you enable on one, you disable on the other.
        // And as you may notice, the order for this operation is disabled first, then enable - VERY VERY IMPORTANT.
        if (show) {
            //     Remove hamburger
            mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
            //  Show back button
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            // when DrawerToggle is disabled i.e. setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false), navigation icon
            // clicks are disabled i.e. the UP button will not work.
            // We need to add a listener, as in below, so DrawerToggle will forward
            // click events to this listener.
        } else {
            // Show hamburger
            mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
        // So, one may think "Hmm why not simplify to:
        // .....
        // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(enable);
        // mDrawer.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(!enable);
        // ......
        // To re-iterate, the order in which you enable and disable views IS important #dontSimplify.
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
//        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
//                onBackPressed();
                if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }
                return true;
        }
//        return false;
//        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        return true;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
            displayImportFrag();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public void displayImportFrag() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        Log.d("called", "new frag");
        ImportFragment importFragment = new ImportFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_frame, importFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
}
```

> ImportFragment.java

```
public class ImportFragment extends Fragment {

    View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.import_fragment, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```